# analysis Fitbit walking and sleeping data

Tags: numpy, pandas, ipython, jupyter-notebook, fitbit

I'm participating in small data analysis competition in our school.
We use Fitbit wearable devices, which is loaned to each participants by host of contest.
For 2 months during the contest, they walk and sleep with this small device 24/7,
allow it to gather data about participant's walk count with heart rate(bpm), etc.
and we need to solve some problems based on these participants' data
like, example,

- show the relations between rainy days and participants' working out rate using the chart,

i think purpose of problem is,
because of rain, lot of participants are expected to be at home.
can you show some cause and effect numerically?

i'm now studying python library numpy, pandas with ipython notebook.
but still i have no idea about solving these problems..
could you recommend some projects or sites use for references? i really eager to win this competition.:(
and lastly, sorry for my poor English.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 2):

that's a fun project. I'm working on something kind of similar.

Here's what you need to do:

- Learn the fitbit API and stream the data from the fitbit accelerometer and gyroscope. If you can combine this with heart rate data, great. The more types of data you have, the more effective your algorithm will be. You can store this data in a simple csv file (streaming the accel/gyro data at 50Hz is recommended). Or setup a web server and store it in a database for easy access
- Learn how to use pandas and scikit learn
- [optional but recommended]: Learn matplotlib so you can graph you data and get a feel for how it looks
- Load the data into pandas and create features on the data - notably using 1-2 second sliding window analysis with 50% overlap. Good features include (for all three Accel X, Y, Z): max, min, standard deviation, root mean square, root sum square and tilt. Polynomials will help.
- Since this is a supervised classification problem, you will need to create some labelled data - so do this manually (state 1 = rainy day, state 2 = non-rainy day) and then train a classification algorithm. I would recommend a [random forest](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html)
- Test using unlabeled data - don't forget to use [cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html)

Voila, you now have a highly accurate model and will win the competition. Plus you've learned about a bunch of really cool Python and machine learning stuff.

For more tutorials on how all this stuff works, I'd highly recommend the [Kaggle tutorial projects](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/details/getting-started-with-python)

BONUS: If you want to take it to a new level, you can start adding smoothers on top of your classifier, for example by using a Hidden Markov Model as explained in [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEwufSsx4O8)

BONUS 2: Go get a PhD in Human Activity Recognition.

Comment: BONUS 2 is nice :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be the other way around (i.e. predict people's work out rate using the weather conditions)?

Comment: I guess you could structure it either way - the reason I answered that way is that the more interesting problem (to me) is using the fitbit data as your classification algorithm features. Yeah instead you could load up the all the weather data - barometer readings, min/max temps, humidity, all that stuff. Could be fun too.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Thanks :)